# NodeJS keep throwing `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE` no matter what

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ssl, websocket

I have a basic nodeJS application that connects to a server via a secured websocket (ws library) connection. When connecting the server keeps throwing a `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE` error. I have no control over the server, it's external. The endpoint starts with `wss://` (not sure if it makes a difference)

I have tried so many things, but none of them seem to work:

- `rejectUnauthorized: false` works, but connection breaks after x time with 1006
- `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=[your CA certificate file path]` doesn't work
- `npm config set cafile [your CA certificate file path]` doesn't work
- npm modules syswide-cas or node-ssl-root-cas don't work
- adding `ca: [fs.readFileSync("ca.ca-bundle", {encoding: 'utf-8'})]` in socket options doesn't work

However, when I navigate in a browser to the endpoint, the connection is valid and secured. I tried extracting the certificates from the browser and included into nodeJS, no results, same error. The same goes for when I use the website `https://whatsmychaincert.com/` to get the certificates ...

Basic code:

```
this.websocket = new WebSocket(this.apiUrl, this.applicationId, {
        rejectUnauthorized: true, 
    });

...

this.websocket.on('open', () => {
        console.log('Connection successfully opened');
    });


this.websocket.on('error', error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

No matter what I do, it seems that regardless the included certificates NodeJS keeps throwing me the `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE` error.

Somebody any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

After days and days of trying to solve this I finally managed to solve this issue!

I was using the wrong certificate chain the whole time. The endpoint which I'm connecting to has a `wss://` prefix. But I was getting the certificates from the url with the `https://` prefix. Apparently this has a different certificate chain.